# How do you run Server Manager in English on a non-English desktop?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to use Server Manager to manage windows servers on my organization. But, since my organization desktops are Windows 10 Portuguese, I can't run Server Manager in English.

Are there any way to force (or hack) Server Manager language to English?

Comment: Install the english language pack inside your OS

Comment: By installing english language pack, can I run windows in portuguese and use server manager in english?